# How can I fix NXDOMAIN error?

Tags: domain

I have recently moved my blog to another hosting company.
The problem is that I cannot access my blog from my macbook pro although at the same time I can see it from my sony vaio.
Going at the terminal and running : nslookup blog.myblogname.org I get the following results:

Server: xx.xx.x.xxx
Address: xx.xx.x.xxx#53

** server can't find blog.myblogname.org: NXDOMAIN

(Server is my isp's domain name server)

Any ideas how to fix that error so that I am able to access my blog from my macbook pro?
Thank you!

PS : My operating system is MAC OS 10.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `dscacheutil -flushcache` in the terminal on the Mac.

Comment: I just tried it but I still cannot access my blog.Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: Perhaps your dns server has the NXDOMAIN still in the cache. Check if you can resolve the IP by using: "host blog.myblogname.org 8.8.8.8" If so, don't worry, NXDOMAIN isn't cached for very long anyway in most cases.

Comment: I tried your host command (8.8.8.8 is google dns?) and I get the following result -> Host blog.myblogname.org not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Comment: I don't know if that matters, but I connect my macbook pro wirelessly to an airport express (that is connected to the router) and the sony vaio wirelessly to the router.

Comment: It seems that it was a matter of time as you say in your second comment! :) Everything works fine suddenly.

Comment: The problem appeared again! :(

Comment: Your host command gives another result now :

Comment: blog.myblogname.org has address xxx.xxx.xx.xx  
Host blog.devcanvas.org not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)  
Host blog.devcanvas.org not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Comment: Nslookup from dos is using my router and nslookup from mac is using isp dns servers.I don't know if this comment helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was showing up when I tried to access my Blogger site via the Indian domain (blogspot.in). Accessing it via the blogspot.com domain made the error go away.